# Sheet freeze for excel using JXL jar

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I'm creating a excel file in java using JXL jar,
and I'm using th following code to freeze the row.

```
   Label lable = new Label(0, 6, "Sl No", tableSubHeaderCellFormat);
   sheet.addCell(lable);
   sheet.mergeCells(0, 6, 0, 7);
   sheet.getSettings().setVerticalFreeze(11);
```

The freeze works fine, but since the freeze is applied (here to the 11th row) to the entire row,
a line continues to appear along the row which is being freezed, and I don't want that line to appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the normal freeze line that appears in excel? Take a look at this if so. http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/dealing-with-the-freeze-panes-line/

Comment: Nope that's not the case....

Comment: I solved this by removing the borders for the cells.